# Why cant I start a process without using ShellExecute set to true?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

So I'm currently trying to start the Command Prompt window from my ASP.NET Core MVC WebApp which is running in Debug mode when I click a button but for some reason it won't start unless I specify `UseShellExecute` and set it to True.

This is a problem since if I do set it to True I can't redirect standard input which is a bad thing.
I need to be able to do that.

Here is the code

```cs
public static void Start(string dirPath)
{
    Process serverProcess = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = "",
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized,
            RedirectStandardInput = true
        }
    };   

    serverProcess.Start()
}
```

It does invoke the code, because keep in mind, it works when I do `UseShellExecute = True` and it also hits the breakpoints etc.

How do I start the cmd or a specific batch file without setting UseShellExecute = True ?

Comment: probably because cmd.exe isnt in the working folder.

Comment: umm using arguments to execute what you need would do the trick.

Comment: I tried changing the working directory to the System32 folder where CMD is located but it wont start

Comment: Also, I can run Notepad.exe but not cmd.exe

Answer (score 1):

`UseShellExecute` is false by default for Core . If you don't want to set `UseShellExecute` . Try setting `Arguments` below as workaround :

```
Arguments = $"/c start cmd.exe",
```

Reference : https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/21767

Comment: I can't seem to redirect input to the cmd though, it's af it's not connected to the process I created